# How to remove Post Job Cleanup step in Team Services?

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

We've recently downloaded and are hosting an on-premises Visual Studio Team Services build agent for our source code and have noticed that it's doing an extra step in the build process compared to our hosted agent. This extra step is the 'Post Job Cleanup' as seen below:

[image]

When setting up this agent locally there was no options for setting this, and looking at our build steps this extra job isn't listed there:

[image]

I've checked online guides but there's been no hint as to where this extra step is coming from. Does anyone know where the option is to include/exclude this for builds is?

Comment: Post Job Cleanup task should be also executed in Hosted Build Agent, can you check this? And why do you want to disable this step?

Comment: I would like to be able to remove this step sometimes as well so I can have a look at the build output whilst debugging builds when I can't get the "Copy and Publish Build Artifact" steps to work

Comment: @AranMulholland You can't log on Hosted Agent to check build output, all the source file and output will be cleaned after build, in order to save the machine resource. You can check the build log for build details.

Comment: Yeah but if you have a private build agent you can.

Answer (score 1):

Setting process.clean to false in the variables of the release pipeline stops the "finalize job" step from killing all processes.

[Setting variables in the release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvUce.png)

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/498153/view.html

[Gradle Daemon being killed in "Finalize Job" step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634453/gradle-daemon-being-killed-in-finalize-job-step)

Comment: Can you add some of the information from the links to the answer? That would make it much more helpful on SO.

Answer (score -1):

They are the built-in steps and there isn’t the way to remove them (Get source, Post Job Cleanup) in VSTS, you don’t need to worry it, it won’t affect your project or build.

Comment: We were able to resolve this by reusing the installation files for our pre-existing agent (this didn't have the Post Job Cleanup). I think the newer agents which MS make available for download have this step pre-configured, but as of yet we haven't found where this is set. The Post Job Cleanup was really increasing our build time which became a blocker when a lot of devs were doing check-ins

Comment: @Novastorm There isn't the way to remove it if you are using Hosted build agent. If it takes a lot time, you need to use on premise build agent instead.

Comment: The above was an on premise one, sorry should have mentioned in my original post.

Comment: @Novastorm I knew what you mean in original post, the on premise build agent is required for your requirement

Comment: @Novastorm Regarding Hosted Build agent, it must to clear something that build used or generated, so Post Job Cleanup is required.